# How to use Google Maps API v2 with API level 10?

Tags: android, google-maps

According to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alk9D.png) the code posted there can be used for Android API 12 or later. I tried the code on an emulator having API level 10 (Google API platform 2.3.3) and I get the following famous error:

`E/AndroidRuntime(  429): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example..../com.example....MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment`

I copy-paste my .xml file below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

So I assume the fragment element is not supported...(?). I tried the same code in an emulator with API level 17 and I get that message (which as I am reading is currently an issue of the emulator):

```
This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services.
```

I do not have a real device having level 17 to test it, but I assume that it might work.

Do I have any mistake in the above code specifically for level 10? What is the code currently supported by Google, in order to develop maps in an android device with API level 10?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alk9D.png) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

UPDATE:
After changing to `FragmentActivity` and `SupportMapFragment` I get the following:

`W/dalvikvm( 6718): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/a/du; (406)`
`W/dalvikvm( 6718): Link of class 'Lmaps/a/du;' failed`
`W/dalvikvm( 6718): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/a/ej; (2358)`
`W/dalvikvm( 6718): Link of class 'Lmaps/a/ej;' failed`
`W/dalvikvm( 6718): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/j/k; (2374)`
`W/dalvikvm( 6718): Link of class 'Lmaps/j/k;' failed` 
`E/dalvikvm( 6718): Could not find class 'maps.j.k', referenced from method maps.
y.ae.a`
`W/dalvikvm( 6718): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 3566 (Lmaps/j/k;) in Lmap
s/y/ae;`
`D/dalvikvm( 6718): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x007d`
`D/dalvikvm( 6718): VFY: dead code 0x007f-008f in Lmaps/y/ae;.a(Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;Z)Lmaps/y/ae;`

And after 2 seconds:
`Google Maps Android API Authorization failure`

UPDATE 2:
I changed the project to build target for android 10 (I had it for android 4.2). So now I do not see the authorization failure). I also paste my api accesses from google [image: api accesses].

I do not have proguard enabled in my .properties of the project i.e.,:
 
`# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available     properties: sdk.dir, user.home):`
`#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt`

`# Project target.`
`target=android-10`
`android.library.reference.1=../../adt-bundle-windows-x86/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib`

The problem still remains:

`01-12 09:57:36.306: D/dalvikvm(9072): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/content/res/Configuration;.smallestScreenWidthDp`
`01-12 09:57:36.306: W/dalvikvm(9072): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 24`
`01-12 09:57:36.306: D/dalvikvm(9072): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012`
`01-12 09:57:36.306: D/dalvikvm(9072): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (Landroid/content/res/Resources;)Z`
`01-12 09:57:36.326: W/dalvikvm(1914): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false`
`01-12 09:57:36.446: D/dalvikvm(9072): GC_CONCURRENT freed 186K, 45% free 3135K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 3ms+2ms`
`01-12 09:57:36.476: W/dalvikvm(9072): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/a/du; (406)`
`01-12 09:57:36.476: W/ResourceType(7905): getEntry failing because entryIndex 303 is beyond type entryCount 133`
`01-12 09:57:36.476: W/ResourceType(7905): Failure getting entry for 0x7f02012f (t=1 e=303) in package 0 (error -2147483647)`
`01-12 09:57:36.476: W/ResourceType(7905): getEntry failing because entryIndex 827 is beyond type entryCount 133`
`01-12 09:57:36.476: W/dalvikvm(9072): Link of class 'Lmaps/a/du;' failed`
`01-12 09:57:36.476: W/dalvikvm(9072): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/a/ej; (2358)`
`01-12 09:57:36.476: W/dalvikvm(9072): Link of class 'Lmaps/a/ej;' failed`
`01-12 09:57:36.476: W/dalvikvm(9072): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/j/k; (2374)`
`01-12 09:57:36.476: W/dalvikvm(9072): Link of class 'Lmaps/j/k;' failed`
`01-12 09:57:36.486: E/dalvikvm(9072): Could not find class 'maps.j.k', referenced from method maps.y.ae.a`
`01-12 09:57:36.486: W/dalvikvm(9072): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 3566 (Lmaps/j/k;) in Lmaps/y/ae;`
`01-12 09:57:36.486: D/dalvikvm(9072): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x007d`
`01-12 09:57:36.496: D/dalvikvm(9072): VFY: dead code 0x007f-008f in Lmaps/y/ae;.a (Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;Z)Lmaps/y/ae;`
`01-12 09:57:36.546: I/keystore(1270): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4`
`01-12 09:57:36.556: I/keystore(1270): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4`
`<01-12 09:57:36.576: W/ResourceType(7905): Failure getting entry for 0x7f02033b (t=1 e=827) in package 0 (error -2147483647)`
`01-12 09:57:36.576: V/WindowManager(1369): Finished animation in AppWindowToken{410a0930 token=HistoryRecord{4099f2f0 com.example..../.MainActivity}} @ 20019326`
`01-12 09:57:36.596: W/ResourceType(7905): getEntry failing because entryIndex 303 is beyond type entryCount 133`
`01-12 09:57:36.616: W/ResourceType(7905): Failure getting entry for 0x7f02012f (t=1 e=303) in package 0 (error -2147483647)`
`01-12 09:57:36.616: W/ResourceType(7905): getEntry failing because entryIndex 827 is beyond type entryCount 133`
`01-12 09:57:36.616: W/ResourceType(7905): Failure getting entry for 0x7f02033b (t=1 e=827) in package 0 (error -2147483647)`
`01-12 09:57:36.686: D/dalvikvm(9072): GC_CONCURRENT freed 276K, 45% free 3257K/5895K, external 0K/0K, paused 4ms+9ms`
`01-12 09:57:36.876: I/keystore(1270): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4`
`01-12 09:57:37.026: D/ATRecorder(9072): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@405d2328`
`01-12 09:57:37.046: D/WindowManagerImpl(9072): addView, new view, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405220f0`
`01-12 09:57:37.056: I/keystore(1270): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4`
`01-12 09:57:37.117: D/PhoneApp(1491): EVENT_QUERY_MO_PACKAGES`
`01-12 09:57:37.137: D/libEGL(9072): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so`
`01-12 09:57:37.147: D/WindowManagerImpl(1369): finishRemoveViewLocked, mViews[1]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40957078`
`01-12 09:57:37.147: I/ActivityManager(1369): Displayed com.example..../.MainActivity: +931ms`
.
`01-12 09:57:37.147: W/SchedPolicy(9072): add_tid_to_cgroup failed to write '' (Invalid argument); background=0`
`01-12 09:57:37.157: D/libEGL(9072): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so`
`01-12 09:57:37.157: W/InputManagerService(1369): [unbindCurrentClientLocked] Disable input method client.`
`01-12 09:57:37.157: W/InputManagerService(1369): [startInputLocked] Enable input method client.`
`01-12 09:57:37.187: D/libEGL(9072): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so`

Comment: I have the same problem "Could not find class 'maps.j.k', referenced from method maps.y.ae.a" I'm running on a Nexus One with version 2.3.6 I've tried the following: 1. Made sure my console had Android Maps Api V2 selected
2. Re-created my API key (I'm not getting an authorization error)
3. Changed my target to Google API 4.2
4. Used SupportMapFragment and FragmentActivity
5. Checked my manifest entries against the provided sample code
6. Checked that google play services library is included
7. Updated google maps, and google play on my device I'm not sure what else there is to try.

Answer (score 15):

instead of using `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment` use `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment` and for the `Activity` it will have to switched to be `FragmentActivity` as mentioned in the comment below

Comment: Also, use `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`.

Comment: Ok but now I have this error on a real device:  `Could not find class maps.j.k, referenced from method maps.y.ae.a`

Comment: can you submit the full stack trace ?

Comment: Make sure your build target is the Google API target.

Comment: from the error Google Maps Android API Authorization failure did you create your authorization code throught API Console ?

Comment: Yes I suppose I have created it. But this error comes after the first messages related to the classes. When does the authorization take place before these errors or afterwards?

Comment: if you have proguard turned on please turn it off so we can see the real log., the authorization error should be the first error thrown i guess , or try to use Google APIs as build target

Comment: @Alex also check if you have selected the Google Maps Android API v2 service from API Console

Answer (score 6):

i use below code hope use full to you:-

**packages and extend**

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class UserLocation extends FragmentActivity
```

**code**

```
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
```

works for me.

**SupportMapFragment**

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html

Comment: Hi, What is this "SupportMapFragment" , I am not getting it in my eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

For earlier APIs, you need to use `SupportmapFragment`.  See the [SupportMapFragment docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment), Basically use `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` instead of `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`

Answer (score 0):

{
Use this as a Reference for codes..
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

also in the above example one has to use his own Api Key in metadata tag of manifest 
instructions for generating Api key are given
}

now if you want to implement this code in android 2.3

---

1)first change the Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

then Rightclick>Properties>Android>Android 2.3

---

2)there are two google play service libraries

```
   a)..\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services_froyo\libproject\google-play-services_lib

   b)..\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib
```

if you'r working on android 2.3 **try having the first one a as a library project**
(you will first need to import it as a library project File>import>................)

---

3)then follow instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992551/map-version-2-in-android-2-3)

---

4)see to it that your Google play services app is up to date on your device