# Map version 2 in Android 2.3

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, android-version

I have developed simple Map application using google map version2. It is working fine on Android 4.0 supported devices but not run in Android 2.3(API 10). Now I need to support the same application from API level 10. How to convert the application support from API level 10?

My application is supported the "**google-play-services_lib**".

my code sample.

main.xml:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

java code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
        private GoogleMap mMap;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
           ........
       }
}
```

please help me to support from API 10(Android 2.3).

Comment: If it is working fine on 4.0 please confirm your 2.3 device installed google play services.

Comment: use `SupportMapFragment` which is distributed as a part of *support library* for backward compatibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention API 10

You should use `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment`.

```
<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:id="@+id/map"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

You activity must also extend `FragmentActivity`.

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mMap = fm.getMap();
```

Import

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment

Check the line above the topic Developer's guide

Comment: Thanks, it works, you saved my time. Is lower version can support all the features what support in 4.0s?

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and

```
extends FragmentActivity
```

and

```
mMap =((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();mMap
```