# InflateException on Api 10

Tags: android, version, inflate-exception

i need help! :)

I've created an app that is almost finished, i've been testing it on many devices and many android versions. Everything is working fine on Android L and KitKat, but when i try to open it on Gingerbread, it won't start.

That's my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap googleMap;
LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

    if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
        showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
    } else {

    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    }

    TextView txView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
```

ecc...

and that's the log cat:

```
    09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lifeapps.speedcalc/com.lifeapps.speedcalc.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class fragment
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class fragment
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at com.lifeapps.speedcalc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     ... 11 more
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.lifeapps.speedcalc-1.apk]
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
09-28 09:53:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2766):     ... 21 more
```

The problem is here:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

But i don't know why. Any idea on how to solve my problem?

P.s. Android Manifest is set on minsdkversion: 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google map fragments are available only starting from API level 12+. If you need it for older version you can look at [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265959/how-to-use-google-maps-api-v2-with-api-level-10).